# Running C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk1/platform-tools/adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

Tags: react-native

I try to run `react-native run-android` to install my app on my emulator but errors occurred like this:

`Running C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk1/platform-tools/adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`.

It's obvious that the `\` and `/` was mixed together because I used Win7 system.

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

[I have set the Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94194.png)

[error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX9Cm.png)

Comment: are you installed `java jdk` on your pc?

Comment: Yes, and I also add that to the system's PATH. @ubatin